# Data Table not Allowed to resize column

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview, datatable

I have a datagridview in my VB app.
I cannot resize the columns. I populate the datagridview with a datatable. The property of my datagridview (AllowUserToReziseColumn) is set to true.

[image]

I CAN Resize in the red circle with the green check beside it. But it seems like the rest of it is the Data table. Any insight?

Populate DataGrid Code

```
Using conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
    conn.Open()
    Using comm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlquery, conn)
        Dim rs As SqlDataReader = comm.ExecuteReader
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
        dt.Load(rs)
        datgDXLog.DataSource = dt
    End Using 'comm
    conn.Close()
End Using 'conn
```

I even reiterate allowusertoresizerows in the prepaint

```
 datgDXLog.AllowUserToResizeColumns = True
        If datgDXLog.Rows.Count >= 3 Then
            If datgDXLog.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value >= 3 Then
                datgDXLog.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red
            End If
        End If
```

I believe my problem is the fact that it is a data table. It makes me think that the datagridview properties do not control this, however I can reorder the column headers when I change the property (AllowUsertoOrderColumns) to True.

Comment: are you using native DataGridView or any third party control?

Comment: Native, The one in the toolbox

Comment: Does the cursor appearance change when you move it over the spot you'd use to change the column size?

Comment: Only in the circle with the check mark. When I hover over the Column borders in the other red circles with the red X by them, my cursor does nothing.

Comment: @UPGRAYEDD I just run the test in VS2012. To double confirm, I used your data fetching logic. The columns auto-reize on double click and manual resize on drag-drop. Working perfect. Try isolating the target code into another project to confirm if some other portion of code is interfering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at your DGV columns' [DataGridViewColumn.AutoSizeMode property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.autosizemode.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) values.

Make sure they're set to either `DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None` or `DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.NotSet`.

Comment: This is what it was. Apparently When I Want to FILL the dataGrid it over writes users to expand the columns. Any work arounds to AutoFill And userallowed Resizing?

Comment: @UPGRAYEDD No sorry, I don't.